# Función para leer json no reconoce enteros SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

Qué tal amigos, estoy leyendo un json con una función. La función separa todo lo que trae el json por objetos, el problema es cuando encuentra un elemento entero, no lo reconoce, estuve revisando la función y separa todos los datos por comillas, dentro un json los enteros no llevan comillas se escriben por si solo.

> select * FROM parseJSON(@json) where ValueType = 'int'
>   IF OBJECT_ID('idstemp') is not null DROP TABLE idstemp

Ahí estoy usando la función donde **@json** es un cadena enorme

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la función que estoy utilizando

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[parseJSON]( @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX))
    RETURNS @hierarchy TABLE
      (
       element_id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, /* internal surrogate primary key gives the order of parsing and the list order */
       sequenceNo [int] NULL, /* the place in the sequence for the element */
       parent_ID INT,/* if the element has a parent then it is in this column. The document is the ultimate parent, so you can get the structure from recursing from the document */
       Object_ID INT,/* each list or object has an object id. This ties all elements to a parent. Lists are treated as objects here */
       NAME NVARCHAR(2000),/* the name of the object */
       StringValue NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,/*the string representation of the value of the element. */
       ValueType VARCHAR(10) NOT null /* the declared type of the value represented as a string in StringValue*/
      )
    AS
    BEGIN
      DECLARE
        @FirstObject INT, --the index of the first open bracket found in the JSON string
        @OpenDelimiter INT,--the index of the next open bracket found in the JSON string
        @NextOpenDelimiter INT,--the index of subsequent open bracket found in the JSON string
        @NextCloseDelimiter INT,--the index of subsequent close bracket found in the JSON string
        @Type NVARCHAR(10),--whether it denotes an object or an array
        @NextCloseDelimiterChar CHAR(1),--either a '}' or a ']'
        @Contents NVARCHAR(MAX), --the unparsed contents of the bracketed expression
        @Start INT, --index of the start of the token that you are parsing
        @end INT,--index of the end of the token that you are parsing
        @param INT,--the parameter at the end of the next Object/Array token
        @EndOfName INT,--the index of the start of the parameter at end of Object/Array token
        @token NVARCHAR(200),--either a string or object
        @value NVARCHAR(MAX), -- the value as a string
        @SequenceNo int, -- the sequence number within a list
        @name NVARCHAR(200), --the name as a string
        @parent_ID INT,--the next parent ID to allocate
        @lenJSON INT,--the current length of the JSON String
        @characters NCHAR(36),--used to convert hex to decimal
        @result BIGINT,--the value of the hex symbol being parsed
        @index SMALLINT,--used for parsing the hex value
        @Escape INT --the index of the next escape character

      DECLARE @Strings TABLE /* in this temporary table we keep all strings, even the names of the elements, since they are 'escaped' in a different way, and may contain, unescaped, brackets denoting objects or lists. These are replaced in the JSON string by tokens representing the string */
        (
         String_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
         StringValue NVARCHAR(MAX)
        )
      SELECT--initialise the characters to convert hex to ascii
        @characters='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        @SequenceNo=0, --set the sequence no. to something sensible.
      /* firstly we process all strings. This is done because [{} and ] aren't escaped in strings, which complicates an iterative parse. */
        @parent_ID=0;
      WHILE 1=1 --forever until there is nothing more to do
        BEGIN
          SELECT
            @start=PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z]["]%', @json collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin);--next delimited string
          IF @start=0 BREAK --no more so drop through the WHILE loop
          IF SUBSTRING(@json, @start+1, 1)='"' 
            BEGIN --Delimited Name
              SET @start=@Start+1;
              SET @end=PATINDEX('%[^\]["]%', RIGHT(@json, LEN(@json+'|')-@start) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin);
            END
          IF @end=0 --no end delimiter to last string
            BREAK --no more
          SELECT @token=SUBSTRING(@json, @start+1, @end-1)
          --now put in the escaped control characters
          SELECT @token=REPLACE(@token, FROMString, TOString)
          FROM
            (SELECT
              '\"' AS FromString, '"' AS ToString
             UNION ALL SELECT '\\', '\'
             UNION ALL SELECT '\/', '/'
             UNION ALL SELECT '\b', CHAR(08)
             UNION ALL SELECT '\f', CHAR(12)
             UNION ALL SELECT '\n', CHAR(10)
             UNION ALL SELECT '\r', CHAR(13)
             UNION ALL SELECT '\t', CHAR(09)
            ) substitutions
          SELECT @result=0, @escape=1
      --Begin to take out any hex escape codes
          WHILE @escape>0
            BEGIN
              SELECT @index=0,
              --find the next hex escape sequence
              @escape=PATINDEX('%\x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]%', @token collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)
              IF @escape>0 --if there is one
                BEGIN
                  WHILE @index<4 --there are always four digits to a \x sequence   
                    BEGIN
                      SELECT --determine its value
                        @result=@result+POWER(16, @index)
                        *(CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@token, @escape+2+3-@index, 1),
                                    @characters)-1), @index=@index+1 ;

                    END
                    -- and replace the hex sequence by its unicode value
                  SELECT @token=STUFF(@token, @escape, 6, NCHAR(@result))
                END
            END
          --now store the string away 
          INSERT INTO @Strings (StringValue) SELECT @token
          -- and replace the string with a token
          SELECT @JSON=STUFF(@json, @start, @end+1,
                        '@string'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), @@identity))
        END
      -- all strings are now removed. Now we find the first leaf.  
      WHILE 1=1  --forever until there is nothing more to do
      BEGIN

      SELECT @parent_ID=@parent_ID+1
      --find the first object or list by looking for the open bracket
      SELECT @FirstObject=PATINDEX('%[{[[]%', @json collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)--object or array
      IF @FirstObject = 0 BREAK
      IF (SUBSTRING(@json, @FirstObject, 1)='{') 
        SELECT @NextCloseDelimiterChar='}', @type='object'
      ELSE 
        SELECT @NextCloseDelimiterChar=']', @type='array'
      SELECT @OpenDelimiter=@firstObject
      WHILE 1=1 --find the innermost object or list...
        BEGIN
          SELECT
            @lenJSON=LEN(@JSON+'|')-1
      --find the matching close-delimiter proceeding after the open-delimiter
          SELECT
            @NextCloseDelimiter=CHARINDEX(@NextCloseDelimiterChar, @json,
                                          @OpenDelimiter+1)
      --is there an intervening open-delimiter of either type
          SELECT @NextOpenDelimiter=PATINDEX('%[{[[]%',
                 RIGHT(@json, @lenJSON-@OpenDelimiter)collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)--object
          IF @NextOpenDelimiter=0 
            BREAK
          SELECT @NextOpenDelimiter=@NextOpenDelimiter+@OpenDelimiter
          IF @NextCloseDelimiter<@NextOpenDelimiter 
            BREAK
          IF SUBSTRING(@json, @NextOpenDelimiter, 1)='{' 
            SELECT @NextCloseDelimiterChar='}', @type='object'
          ELSE 
            SELECT @NextCloseDelimiterChar=']', @type='array'
          SELECT @OpenDelimiter=@NextOpenDelimiter
        END
      ---and parse out the list or name/value pairs
      SELECT
        @contents=SUBSTRING(@json, @OpenDelimiter+1,
                            @NextCloseDelimiter-@OpenDelimiter-1)
      SELECT
        @JSON=STUFF(@json, @OpenDelimiter,
                    @NextCloseDelimiter-@OpenDelimiter+1,
                    '@'+@type+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), @parent_ID))
      WHILE (PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z0-9@+.e]%', @contents collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin))<>0 
        BEGIN
          IF @Type='Object' --it will be a 0-n list containing a string followed by a string, number,boolean, or null
            BEGIN
              SELECT
                @SequenceNo=0,@end=CHARINDEX(':', ' '+@contents)--if there is anything, it will be a string-based name.
              SELECT  @start=PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z@][@]%', ' '+@contents collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)--AAAAAAAA
              SELECT @token=SUBSTRING(' '+@contents, @start+1, @End-@Start-1),
                @endofname=PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @token collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin),
                @param=RIGHT(@token, LEN(@token)-@endofname+1)
              SELECT
                @token=LEFT(@token, @endofname-1),
                @Contents=RIGHT(' '+@contents, LEN(' '+@contents+'|')-@end-1)
              SELECT  @name=stringvalue FROM @strings
                WHERE string_id=@param --fetch the name
            END
          ELSE 
            SELECT @Name=null,@SequenceNo=@SequenceNo+1 
          SELECT
            @end=CHARINDEX(',', @contents)-- a string-token, object-token, list-token, number,boolean, or null
                IF @end=0
            --HR Engineering notation bugfix start
              IF ISNUMERIC(@contents) = 1
            SELECT @end = LEN(@contents)
              Else
            --HR Engineering notation bugfix end 
          SELECT  @end=PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z0-9@+.e][^A-Za-z0-9@+.e]%', @contents+' ' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin) + 1
           SELECT
            @start=PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z0-9@+.e][A-Za-z0-9@+.e]%', ' '+@contents collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)
          --select @start,@end, LEN(@contents+'|'), @contents  
          SELECT
            @Value=RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@contents, @start, @End-@Start)),
            @Contents=RIGHT(@contents+' ', LEN(@contents+'|')-@end)
          IF SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 7)='@object' 
            INSERT INTO @hierarchy
              (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, Object_ID, ValueType)
              SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, SUBSTRING(@value, 8, 5),
                SUBSTRING(@value, 8, 5), 'object' 
          ELSE 
            IF SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 6)='@array' 
              INSERT INTO @hierarchy
                (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, Object_ID, ValueType)
                SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, SUBSTRING(@value, 7, 5),
                  SUBSTRING(@value, 7, 5), 'array' 
            ELSE 
              IF SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 7)='@string' 
                INSERT INTO @hierarchy
                  (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                  SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, stringvalue, 'string'
                  FROM @strings
                  WHERE string_id=SUBSTRING(@value, 8, 5)
              ELSE 
                IF @value IN ('true', 'false') 
                  INSERT INTO @hierarchy
                    (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                    SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, @value, 'boolean'
                ELSE
                  IF @value='null' 
                    INSERT INTO @hierarchy
                      (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                      SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, @value, 'null'
                  ELSE
                    IF PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @value collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)>0 
                      INSERT INTO @hierarchy
                        (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                        SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, @value, 'real'
                    ELSE
                      INSERT INTO @hierarchy
                        (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                        SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, @value, 'int'
          if @Contents=' ' Select @SequenceNo=0
        END
      END
    INSERT INTO @hierarchy (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, Object_ID, ValueType)
      SELECT '-',1, NULL, '', @parent_id-1, @type
    --
       RETURN
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

Al momento de revisar el último elemento del Json, para los enteros no estaba cortando bien los caracteres. Para solucionar esto sin quebrar el código, el proceso verifica si el último elemento es numérico, si es así, no hace un tratamiento con el substring.

Modificación (cerca de la línea: 173):

```
-- antes
SELECT
    @Value=RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@contents, @start, @End-@Start)),
    @Contents=RIGHT(@contents+' ', LEN(@contents+'|')-@end)

-- despúes
IF ISNUMERIC(@contents) = 1
    SELECT
        @Value=RTRIM(LTRIM(@contents)),
        @Contents=RIGHT(@contents+' ', LEN(@contents+'|')-@end)
ELSE 
    SELECT
        @Value=RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@contents, @start, @End-@Start)),
        @Contents=RIGHT(@contents+' ', LEN(@contents+'|')-@end)
```

Código con la modificación:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[parseJSON]( @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX))
    RETURNS @hierarchy TABLE
      (
       element_id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, /* internal surrogate primary key gives the order of parsing and the list order */
       sequenceNo [int] NULL, /* the place in the sequence for the element */
       parent_ID INT,/* if the element has a parent then it is in this column. The document is the ultimate parent, so you can get the structure from recursing from the document */
       Object_ID INT,/* each list or object has an object id. This ties all elements to a parent. Lists are treated as objects here */
       NAME NVARCHAR(2000),/* the name of the object */
       StringValue NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,/*the string representation of the value of the element. */
       ValueType VARCHAR(10) NOT null /* the declared type of the value represented as a string in StringValue*/
      )
    AS
    BEGIN
      DECLARE
        @FirstObject INT, --the index of the first open bracket found in the JSON string
        @OpenDelimiter INT,--the index of the next open bracket found in the JSON string
        @NextOpenDelimiter INT,--the index of subsequent open bracket found in the JSON string
        @NextCloseDelimiter INT,--the index of subsequent close bracket found in the JSON string
        @Type NVARCHAR(10),--whether it denotes an object or an array
        @NextCloseDelimiterChar CHAR(1),--either a '}' or a ']'
        @Contents NVARCHAR(MAX), --the unparsed contents of the bracketed expression
        @Start INT, --index of the start of the token that you are parsing
        @end INT,--index of the end of the token that you are parsing
        @param INT,--the parameter at the end of the next Object/Array token
        @EndOfName INT,--the index of the start of the parameter at end of Object/Array token
        @token NVARCHAR(200),--either a string or object
        @value NVARCHAR(MAX), -- the value as a string
        @SequenceNo int, -- the sequence number within a list
        @name NVARCHAR(200), --the name as a string
        @parent_ID INT,--the next parent ID to allocate
        @lenJSON INT,--the current length of the JSON String
        @characters NCHAR(36),--used to convert hex to decimal
        @result BIGINT,--the value of the hex symbol being parsed
        @index SMALLINT,--used for parsing the hex value
        @Escape INT --the index of the next escape character

      DECLARE @Strings TABLE /* in this temporary table we keep all strings, even the names of the elements, since they are 'escaped' in a different way, and may contain, unescaped, brackets denoting objects or lists. These are replaced in the JSON string by tokens representing the string */
        (
         String_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
         StringValue NVARCHAR(MAX)
        )
      SELECT--initialise the characters to convert hex to ascii
        @characters='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        @SequenceNo=0, --set the sequence no. to something sensible.
      /* firstly we process all strings. This is done because [{} and ] aren't escaped in strings, which complicates an iterative parse. */
        @parent_ID=0;
      WHILE 1=1 --forever until there is nothing more to do
        BEGIN
          SELECT
            @start=PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z]["]%', @json collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin);--next delimited string
          IF @start=0 BREAK --no more so drop through the WHILE loop
          IF SUBSTRING(@json, @start+1, 1)='"' 
            BEGIN --Delimited Name
              SET @start=@Start+1;
              SET @end=PATINDEX('%[^\]["]%', RIGHT(@json, LEN(@json+'|')-@start) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin);
            END
          IF @end=0 --no end delimiter to last string
            BREAK --no more
          SELECT @token=SUBSTRING(@json, @start+1, @end-1)
          --now put in the escaped control characters
          SELECT @token=REPLACE(@token, FROMString, TOString)
          FROM
            (SELECT
              '\"' AS FromString, '"' AS ToString
             UNION ALL SELECT '\\', '\'
             UNION ALL SELECT '\/', '/'
             UNION ALL SELECT '\b', CHAR(08)
             UNION ALL SELECT '\f', CHAR(12)
             UNION ALL SELECT '\n', CHAR(10)
             UNION ALL SELECT '\r', CHAR(13)
             UNION ALL SELECT '\t', CHAR(09)
            ) substitutions
          SELECT @result=0, @escape=1
      --Begin to take out any hex escape codes
          WHILE @escape>0
            BEGIN
              SELECT @index=0,
              --find the next hex escape sequence
              @escape=PATINDEX('%\x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]%', @token collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)
              IF @escape>0 --if there is one
                BEGIN
                  WHILE @index<4 --there are always four digits to a \x sequence   
                    BEGIN
                      SELECT --determine its value
                        @result=@result+POWER(16, @index)
                        *(CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@token, @escape+2+3-@index, 1),
                                    @characters)-1), @index=@index+1 ;

                    END
                    -- and replace the hex sequence by its unicode value
                  SELECT @token=STUFF(@token, @escape, 6, NCHAR(@result))
                END
            END
          --now store the string away 
          INSERT INTO @Strings (StringValue) SELECT @token
          -- and replace the string with a token
          SELECT @JSON=STUFF(@json, @start, @end+1,
                        '@string'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), @@identity))
        END
      -- all strings are now removed. Now we find the first leaf.  
      WHILE 1=1  --forever until there is nothing more to do
      BEGIN

      SELECT @parent_ID=@parent_ID+1
      --find the first object or list by looking for the open bracket
      SELECT @FirstObject=PATINDEX('%[{[[]%', @json collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)--object or array
      IF @FirstObject = 0 BREAK
      IF (SUBSTRING(@json, @FirstObject, 1)='{') 
        SELECT @NextCloseDelimiterChar='}', @type='object'
      ELSE 
        SELECT @NextCloseDelimiterChar=']', @type='array'
      SELECT @OpenDelimiter=@firstObject
      WHILE 1=1 --find the innermost object or list...
        BEGIN
          SELECT
            @lenJSON=LEN(@JSON+'|')-1
      --find the matching close-delimiter proceeding after the open-delimiter
          SELECT
            @NextCloseDelimiter=CHARINDEX(@NextCloseDelimiterChar, @json,
                                          @OpenDelimiter+1)
      --is there an intervening open-delimiter of either type
          SELECT @NextOpenDelimiter=PATINDEX('%[{[[]%',
                 RIGHT(@json, @lenJSON-@OpenDelimiter)collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)--object
          IF @NextOpenDelimiter=0 
            BREAK
          SELECT @NextOpenDelimiter=@NextOpenDelimiter+@OpenDelimiter
          IF @NextCloseDelimiter<@NextOpenDelimiter 
            BREAK
          IF SUBSTRING(@json, @NextOpenDelimiter, 1)='{' 
            SELECT @NextCloseDelimiterChar='}', @type='object'
          ELSE 
            SELECT @NextCloseDelimiterChar=']', @type='array'
          SELECT @OpenDelimiter=@NextOpenDelimiter
        END
      ---and parse out the list or name/value pairs
      SELECT
        @contents=SUBSTRING(@json, @OpenDelimiter+1,
                            @NextCloseDelimiter-@OpenDelimiter-1)
      SELECT
        @JSON=STUFF(@json, @OpenDelimiter,
                    @NextCloseDelimiter-@OpenDelimiter+1,
                    '@'+@type+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), @parent_ID))
      WHILE (PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z0-9@+.e]%', @contents collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin))<>0 
        BEGIN
          IF @Type='Object' --it will be a 0-n list containing a string followed by a string, number,boolean, or null
            BEGIN
              SELECT
                @SequenceNo=0,@end=CHARINDEX(':', ' '+@contents)--if there is anything, it will be a string-based name.
              SELECT  @start=PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z@][@]%', ' '+@contents collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)--AAAAAAAA
              SELECT @token=SUBSTRING(' '+@contents, @start+1, @End-@Start-1),
                @endofname=PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @token collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin),
                @param=RIGHT(@token, LEN(@token)-@endofname+1)
              SELECT
                @token=LEFT(@token, @endofname-1),
                @Contents=RIGHT(' '+@contents, LEN(' '+@contents+'|')-@end-1)
              SELECT  @name=stringvalue FROM @strings
                WHERE string_id=@param --fetch the name
            END
          ELSE 
            SELECT @Name=null,@SequenceNo=@SequenceNo+1 
          SELECT
            @end=CHARINDEX(',', @contents)-- a string-token, object-token, list-token, number,boolean, or null
                IF @end=0
            --HR Engineering notation bugfix start
              IF ISNUMERIC(@contents) = 1
            SELECT @end = LEN(@contents)
              Else
            --HR Engineering notation bugfix end 
          SELECT  @end=PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z0-9@+.e][^A-Za-z0-9@+.e]%', @contents+' ' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin) + 1
           SELECT
            @start=PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z0-9@+.e][A-Za-z0-9@+.e]%', ' '+@contents collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)
          --select @start,@end, LEN(@contents+'|'), @contents  
          IF ISNUMERIC(@contents) = 1
            SELECT
                @Value=RTRIM(LTRIM(@contents)),
                @Contents=RIGHT(@contents+' ', LEN(@contents+'|')-@end)
          ELSE 
          SELECT
            @Value=RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@contents, @start, @End-@Start)),
            @Contents=RIGHT(@contents+' ', LEN(@contents+'|')-@end)
          IF SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 7)='@object' 
            INSERT INTO @hierarchy
              (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, Object_ID, ValueType)
              SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, SUBSTRING(@value, 8, 5),
                SUBSTRING(@value, 8, 5), 'object' 
          ELSE 
            IF SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 6)='@array' 
              INSERT INTO @hierarchy
                (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, Object_ID, ValueType)
                SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, SUBSTRING(@value, 7, 5),
                  SUBSTRING(@value, 7, 5), 'array' 
            ELSE 
              IF SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 7)='@string' 
                INSERT INTO @hierarchy
                  (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                  SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, stringvalue, 'string'
                  FROM @strings
                  WHERE string_id=SUBSTRING(@value, 8, 5)
              ELSE 
                IF @value IN ('true', 'false') 
                  INSERT INTO @hierarchy
                    (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                    SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, @value, 'boolean'
                ELSE
                  IF @value='null' 
                    INSERT INTO @hierarchy
                      (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                      SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, @value, 'null'
                  ELSE
                    IF PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @value collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)>0 
                      INSERT INTO @hierarchy
                        (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                        SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, @value, 'real'
                    ELSE
                      INSERT INTO @hierarchy
                        (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                        SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, @value, 'int'
          if @Contents=' ' Select @SequenceNo=0
        END
      END
    INSERT INTO @hierarchy (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, Object_ID, ValueType)
      SELECT '-',1, NULL, '', @parent_id-1, @type
    --
       RETURN
    END
```